# Confused about this similar for loops with different outputs

Tags: javascript, closures, settimeout

When learning about scope and closures I found an article that confused me (https://wsvincent.com/javascript-scope-closures/)

If I include a setTimeout on the block to execute inside a for loop, I get the output of the setTimeout after the loop finishes. However if I use a custom function invoked inside the loop, this doesn't happen.

```
for (let i=1; i<=5; i++) {
  console.log(i);
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("i: " + i);
  },1000);
}

// Outputs
// 1
// 2
// 3
// 4
// 5
// "i: 1"
// "i: 2"
// "i: 3"
// "i: 4"
// "i: 5"

for (let i=1; i<=5; i++) {
  console.log(i);
  function count () {
    console.log('i: ' + i);
  }
  count();
}

//Outputs
// 1
// "i: 1"
// 2
// "i: 2"
// 3
// "i: 3"
// 4
// "i: 4"
// 5
// "i: 5"
```

Why does it count 1 to 5 first and then logs the setTimeout?

Comment: Because that's how `setTimeout` works - it delays execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because `setTimeout()` creates an assynchronous behavior, since it only run the callback function (that function passed as parameter) after the specified delay (in your case 1000ms).

So, the for loop runs almost instantly since it does nothing but console.log your `i` variable. (It will be executed in less then milissecond probably) Then your timeouts will happen and output the value of `i`.

And here's the trick: your variable `i` belongs to the for closure scope, for this reason it will output incremental values.

If your variable was declared outside for statement, your timeout console.log will output 5 everytime.

Comment: See this https://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/ for more details about variable scope on JS

Answer (score 0):

```
The setTimeout() method calls a function or expression after a specified number of milliseconds.
```

In the for loop you set 1000 milliseconds.
thats why after printing 1 to 5 its called